# Base64 encoded excel file not decoding in email attachments

Tags: php, excel, email, base64

I am creating an excel file and attaching it in an email. The email sends with the excel file attached, but the contents are all mucked up (N¬ŠÆ›j×!­êh®×è®Ø^¥êè‰ÚÓzÛMy¶9×Í´×).

```
$sFileName = "BatchReport".date("Y-m-d");
$eContent = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents(WP_PLUGIN_DIR."/cs-cart/includes/excel/".$sFileName.".xls")));
$sUniqueID = md5(uniqid(time()));

$sHeaders = "From: " . (($sFrom) ? $sFrom : "Cervid Solutions <admin@" . str_replace("www.","",$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]) . ">") . "\n" .
                    "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
                    "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=".$sUniqueID."\n\n" .
                    "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n" .
                    "--".$sUniqueID."\r\n" .
                    "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n" .
                    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n" .
                    $sMessage."\r\n\r\n" .
                    "--".$sUniqueID."\r\n" .
                    "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=".$sFileName.".xls"."\n" .
                    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n" .
                    "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$sFileName.".xls"."\r\n\r\n" .
                    $eContent."\r\n\r\n" .
                    "--".$sUniqueID."--";

wp_mail($sTo, $sSubject, $sMessage, $sHeaders);
```

I have seen other people use this same code, but do not seem to have the same issue with the file contents being decoded properly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your using `wp_mail()` you should not be rolling your own attachment handling.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail

```
wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments )
```

you need to add attachments as per documentation.

in your case:

```
$attachments = array(WP_PLUGIN_DIR."/cs-cart/includes/excel/".$sFileName.".xls");
```

Comment: I just used the regular mail() function. Glad Wordpress doesn't squash that.

Comment: makes more sense to use wordpress in this instance.